# What's the simplest way to change the color of a div by clicking it?

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick, background-color

I'm trying to change the background color of a div when clicked. This is the code I've written:

```
<div style="background-color:red" onClick="this.style='background-color:blue'"></div>
```

For some reason, this hasn't been working. I'm sure it's a syntax problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background color can be referred to as a DOM property : `this.style['background-color']`

```
<div style="background-color:red" onClick="this.style['background-color']='blue'">Demo Text</div>
```

Or as a JS Property : `this.style.backgroundColor`

```
<div style="background-color:red" onClick="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'">Demo Text</div>
```

The later is more popular. The browser ensures that both the DOM property & JS property are in sync.

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8zLn/1/) :

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I appreciate the demo. That looks like a great testing site.

Comment: Could you help explain why we use "backgroundColor" instead of "background-color" in this example? Does it have to do with the code being within the <body> tag instead of the <script> tag? Thanks.

Comment: No, the problem was with the way you use `this.style=`. Please read my answer again, both `"backgroundColor"` & `['background-color']` work. First one is a js property which acts an alias for the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background-color:red" onClick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<div style="background-color:red" onClick="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'"></div>
```